# Does Brahman (the Supreme God) have any emotions?

Tags: brahman, taittirya-upanishad

Does the supreme God have emotions like love, hate, **anger**, like, dislike?

The Taittiriya Upanishad says:

> From **fear** of him (Brahman) the wind (Vayu) blows, from **terror** the Sun rises; from **terror** of it,  Agni and Indra, and Death (Mrtyu) runs as the fifth.

According to me, the above verse in an indirect way is saying that if the wind doesn't blow, the sun doesn't rise, Brahman might get angry and maybe punish them.

So, I'd like to get some explanations on this.

---

<sup>I know the verse I have provide is not that clear but why would any one fear if he will not get angry</sup>

Comment: Nirguna Brahman is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Śūnyatā /Zero or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purusha and transcends gunas or space-time.All these divisions and emotions are in triguna Maya or Bhagwan(with bhaga or divisions), hence gods like Indra, Varuna, Agni, Vishnu etc., call them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ādityas or son of Aditi, personification of Prakriti.However, Purusha-Prakriti appear to same & coming out of one another for bound souls as the one creation is cyclic multiformed for them,"eko ham, bahu syam',"Dakṣa was born of Aditi, and Aditi was Dakṣa's Child"-Rig Veda X.72.4

Comment: Nirguna Brahman does not have any emotion. But Saguna Brahman does and oh yeah you better fear when that gets angry .

Comment: Thats why Upanishads mention Aham Brahmāsmi (अहम् ब्रह्मास्मि) - "I am Brahman" (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10, but learning it does not give instant powers of Brahman to create, maintain and destroy world, because Upanishads are mentioning Nirguna Brahman, default oneness of all, while powers to create and destroy are with Shakti or Saguna Brahman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Brahman has no emotion. The word terror is poetry and should not be taken so literally. The verse is saying that Brahman is making the entire world run through Maya.

> This ancient Hindu system designates the Ultimate Reality as Brahman,
> also described as Satchidananda, Existence-Knowledge-Bliss Absolute.
> Brahman is the only Real Existence. **In it there is no time, no space,
> no causality, no multiplicity.** But through Maya, Its inscrutable Power, time, space and
> causality are created and the One appears to break into the many.

**The gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Introduction, Vedanta by Swami Nikhilananda**

Emotions are created by Brahman even though Brahman is beyond all duality.

> "**That which cannot be comprehended by the mind but by which the mind
> is cognized know that alone to be Brahman**, and not this that people
> worship here."

**(Kena Upanishad I.6)**